# Are any flight schools or clubs in Canada using Pipistrel's Alpha Electro or Velis Electro?

Tags: flight-training, canada, electric-aircraft

I'm interested in the business and environmental possibilities of using electric trainers for training.

Are there flight clubs or flight schools training with electric aircraft?

I thought I'd read that Canada provided some kind of type rating for the Alpha Electro, and I'm hearing that Pipistrel's newer Velis electro is certified (at least in Switzerland).

Is anyone doing this now in Canada? If not, why not? Are there regulatory obstacles?

Comment: Welcome to AviationStackExchange. One drawback to using an electric aircraft in training is the issue of critical mass. There are not enough electric aircraft in the rental and General Aviation inventory to make training in one attractive. I for one would not find it attractive as a student to train in a type of aircraft that I have very little likelihood of flying outside of training.

Comment: Thanks Dean! Appreciate the thoughtful answer.

Comment: I really hope we start seeing more electric aircraft. It would be so much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Pipistrel Electro registered in Canada is an Alpha, C-IZAP, registered to a private owner in British Columbia.  So the answer is for now, no.

Pipistrels, including the Electros, are licenced in Canada as Advanced Ultralights.  I don't see any reason an Electro couldn't be used for training under the Advanced Ultralight regulations (not for Private Pilot however).  Probably cost is an obstacle.

Answer (score 2):

The University of Waterloo has imported Canada's first Pipistrel Velis Electro. This one is for testing, but hopefully it leads to certification and flight schools like our partner Waterloo Wellington Flight Centre will introduce them more widely.
Paul

Comment: OOOOOhhhh cool... thanks Paul! Any clues as to where I might look to spot such an unusual creature?